# Cartesian products on the $x-y$ plane

Tags: elementary-set-theory, coordinate-systems

Sketch this Cartesian product on the $x-y$ plane: $[0,1] \times [0,1]$

So, the Cartesian product of two sets $A$ and $B$ is another set, denoted  as $A \times B$ and defined as $A \times B=\{(a,b): a\in A,\ b\in B\}$. So if I had to find for example the Cartesian product of: $\left\{0,1\right\} \times \left\{0,1\right\}$ then that would be $\left\{(0,0), (0,1), (1, 0), (1,1)\right\}$. So I would essentially get the corner points of a square. I'm confused by the closed brackets in the original problem, what do they represent?

Comment: The aboves are intervals, the cartesian product would be a square from $x \in [0,1]$ and $y \in [0,1]$

Comment: $[0,1]$ is the closed interval $\{x\in\mathbb R\mid 0\le x\le 1\}$.